# Why are strings generated by gsha256sum 512 bits long?

Tags: gnu-coreutils

On MacOS with brew install coreutils, when executing:

```sh
$ SEED="I am a seed"
$ SECRET=$(echo -n $SEED|gsha256sum | cut -d\  -f1)
4beb564ded9dd12eb8de15d5543294eba13463044808e877289dc6df9a521cda
echo -n $SECRET | wc -m
  64
```

Trying to generate a 512bit seed, which is the actual result, but I would assume that gsha256sum returned a 256bit string, not a 512bit string.

Comment: That is a "256bit string". 64*4 = 256.

Comment: But Utf8 is 8 bits per character, (ascii 7), I'm trying to understand why the answer is 

`64 * 4`
rather than 
`64* 8`

Comment: The text you are seeing is the hexadecimal representation of the calculated hash. One hexadecimal digit represents a 4bit value. So you have 64*4 = 256 and not 64*8=512.

Comment: Thank you! To re-state, to visual represent the actual byte, 4 bits are required, and the underlying data it displays is 4 bits

Comment: One byte is 8 bits, not 4 bits. So you need two hexadecimal values to get one byte value. That's why you use notations like `0x00` and `0xFF` for the possible byte values shown in hexadecimal.

Comment: Or in other words, a single character in a hexadecimal string can take on one of 16 values, i.e., represents 4 bits (2^4 = 16).